# puppet inserts two lines as one into a configuration file

Tags: linux, puppet, centos6, puppetmaster, vnc

I've created the next Puppet manifest file:

```
node 'puppetmaster' {
    package { "screen": ensure => "installed"}
    $enhancers = [ "pixman","pixman-devel","libXfont","tigervnc-server" ]
    package { $enhancers: ensure => "installed" }
    file { '/etc/skel/.vimrc':
    content => ":set nu\n :set incsearch\n :set ignorecase\n :set smartcase\n:set ts=2",}
    file { '/root/.vimrc':
    content => ":set nu\nset incsearch\n:set ignorecase\n:set smartcase\n:set ts=2",}
    file { '/etc/sysconfig/vncserver':
    content => 'VNCSERVERS="6:root"\nVNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"',}
 }
```

After applying the manifest, I check `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver` and it looks like this:

```
VNCSERVERS=6:root\nVNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"
```

Instead of being separated to two lines like this:

```
VNCSERVERS=6:root
VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"
```

I used the same format when setting the `/etc/skel/.vimrc` file and it worked like a charm so I don't understand why it doesn't work while trying to set `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver`, I believe it has something to do with the double quotes `""`.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double quotes (`"`") instead of single quotes (`'`).  Much like the shell, perl, and other languages, single quotes in Puppet indicate a literal string and inhibit variable interpolation and the interpretation of backslash-escapes.

```
file { '/etc/sysconfig/vncserver':
  content => "VNCSERVERS=\"6:root\"\nVNCSERVERARGS[6]=\"-geometry 1152x864\"",}
```

Notice that I've had to escape the double quotes inside the string.